# Fat Free Framework 3 render arbitrary HTML (not from files)

Tags: fat-free-framework

I was wondering if it would be somehow possibile to render a HTML code portion if this is not lying inside an actual .html file.

You usually do:

```
$template = new Template;
echo $template->render('whatever.html');
```

But I'd really like to do:

```
$template = new Template;
$rendered_content = $template->render($my_html_code);
```

The reason is: I have created several email templates and it would be great if I could use F3 template engine to replace placeholder variables I've put inside these, and have the final processed HTML code ready to be sent via email.

I know I could probably dump the template to a temp .html file, but this sounds a bit ugly to me, and I'd rather not go through this way unless no other options are available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the `resolve()` method:

```php
$tpl = new Template;
$rendered_content = $tpl->resolve($my_html_code);
```

This method is enough for replacing "placeholder variables", such as `My name is {{ @name }}`.

If you also intend to use template tags (`<repeat>`, `<check>`, etc..), you need first to `parse()` the string, and then pass the result to `resolve()`. E.g:

```php
$tpl = new Template;
$rendered_content = $tpl->resolve($tpl->parse($my_html_code));
```

Comment: Nice. We're not quite there yet though. The `resolve` method doesn't seem to like arrays very much. Within my `<repeat>` tags I get: `<repeat group="Array" value="">` and everything gets blown up. Wonder why?

Comment: The `resolve()` method is enough for replacing "placeholder variables", as you requested. If you also intend to use the full set of template tags, you need to first `parse()` the string and pass the result to `resolve()`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Gotcha. I had solved with your second comment alone even before you edited the question. Looks like we have a winner... thanks :)